# How to change background color conditionally?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the color of background.
I am changing every odd results to light green(#f0f5f5) so when the result ends in even number,
I get big white space.
I would like to change background color of pagination section to light green when the result ends in even number.
Sear
search results displays only 5 results so it could be 2th and 4th.

```js
search.addWidgets([
  instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
    container: '#searchbox',
  }),
  instantsearch.widgets.hits({
    container: '#Algolia_Result',
    transformItems: function (items) {
      return items.map(function (item) {
        if (item.objectType === 'Startup') {
          item._isDescription = isNotNull(item.description);
  
        } else if (item.objectType === 'NEWS') {
          item._isSource = isNotNull(item.source);

        } else if (item.objectType === 'Comment') {
            
          item._isComment = isNotNull(item.comment);
         
     
        return item;
      });
    },
     templates: {
      empty: '<div id="empty">No results have been found for {{ query }}.</div><br>',
      item: `
        <a href="{{linkUrl}}" target="_blank">
        <div class="algolia_container">
            <div class="item1">
                <div id="images"><img src="{{logoUrl}}" alt="{{hits-image}}" id="hits-image"></div>
                <div id="objTyeps"><span class="objectType {{objectCss}}">{{objectType}}</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item2">
                <div id="objectTitle">
                <span id="titleForDisplay">{{#helpers.highlight}}{ "attribute": "titleForDisplay" }{{/helpers.highlight}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item3">


                {{#_isLocation}}
                    <div id="location">{{#helpers.highlight}}{ "attribute": "location" }{{/helpers.highlight}}</div>
                {{/_isLocation}}
                
            </div>
        </div></a>
      `, 
    },
  }),
  instantsearch.widgets.pagination({
    container: '#pagination',
  }),
]);
```

```css
#Algolia_Result > div > div > ol > li:nth-child(odd){background-color: #f0f5f5;}

.ais-Pagination-item {
    display:inline;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
    border-radius:5px;
    font-size:18px;
}

.ais-Pagination-list {
    text-align: center;
    height:45px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.ais-Pagination-item:hover {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  transition: background-color .2s;
}

.ais-Pagination-item--selected{
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchbox"></div>      
    <div id="results">
        <div id="Algolia_Result"></div>
        <div id="pagination"></div>
    </div>
```

[This is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq8os.jpg)

[This need be fixed as if the background color of pagination area is the same as the last result, it must be green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWHlz.jpg)

[This is what I get in the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckvIE.jpg)

Comment: Please update your code to something that's reproducible. Currently there's an error in your code causing the snippet to not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can color background of the pagination row by using JavaScript to count the number of results and apply color if the number of results is even.

Check out the example below.

Example 1 is with an **odd** number of result rows and the CSS works fine, same as your working example.

Example 2 is with an **even** number of result rows and uses the JS code to style the pagination background.

```js
// Count the rows
let numRows = document.querySelectorAll('#example-2 .row').length
// If the number of rows is even
if (numRows % 2 == 0) {
  // Apply the background color to the pagination row
  document.querySelector('#example-2 .pagination').style.backgroundColor = '#eee'
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
Example 1
<div id="example-1" class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="row">Row 1</div>
    <div class="row">Row 2</div>
    <div class="row">Row 3</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="pageination">Pagination Row</div>
  </div>
</div>

Example 2
<div id="example-2" class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="row">Row 1</div>
    <div class="row">Row 2</div>
  <div>
  <div>
    <div class="pagination">Pagination Row</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: So in your example, you would add the following JavaScript.

```html
<script>
  let numRows = document.querySelectorAll('.ais-Hits-item').length
  if (numRows % 2 == 0) {
    document.querySelector('.ais-Pagination-list').style.backgroundColor = '#eee'
  }
</script>
```

EDIT 2: Looking at your code sandbox I can see that the issue is that the JS that counts the number of rows is being run *before* the rows have been rendered by Algolia.

To solve this issue we need to place our row counting JS into an Algolia callback that is ran *after* the rows have been rendered. We can use the algolia `search.on('render', ...)` event callback.

Try this:

```js
search.on('render', () => {
  let numRows = document.querySelectorAll('.algolia_container').length;
  if (numRows % 2 === 0) {
    document.querySelector('#pagination').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#pagination').style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  }
});
```

Comment: I've added an example with your classes

Comment: so I checked that 
let numRows = document.querySelectorAll('.ais-Hits-list').length;
returns 0 length.

Comment: Try `document.querySelectorAll('#Algolia_Result li').length`

Comment: I have created codesandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-leftpad-zpk2v?file=/src/app.js

Comment: I've had a look at your sandbox and added a second edit to my answer, let me know if it works!